# Demonstrate series of Maclaurin

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

> Find the Maclaurin series of $$f(x)=xe^x$$ Integrate this series term by term in the closed interval $[0,1]$ and demonstrate that:
>   $$\sum^\infty_{2} \frac{1}{(n-2){} !n}  =  1$$

I tried it:

Formula for Maclaurin series:
$$f(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+\frac{x^2}{2 !}f''(0)+...+\frac{x^n}{n !}f^{(n)}(0)+...$$
Therefore I have the following data:
$$f(x)=xe^x$$
$$f(0)=xe^0=0$$
$$f'(x)=e^x+xe^x\implies f'(0)=1$$ 
$$f'(x)=e^x+e^x+xe^x=2e^x+xe^x\implies f''(0)=2$$
$$...$$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$xe^x=x\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{k+1}}{k!}\implies$$

$$\int_0^1xe^xdx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\int_0^1x^{k+1}dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!(k+2)}$$

Now do by parts the left integral.

Comment: ohh thanks,, :)